# How to set Armenian font for Text Input in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pysimplegui

I have a simple GUI code that accepts English and even Russian input but not Armenian, tried to input "Arial Armenian" font in code but it doesnt work, getting "?"-s instead of letters.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Define a font that supports Armenian characters
font = ('Arial Armenian', 12, 'normal')
sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color

# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
        [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText(font=font)],
        [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()
```

Comment: Check if the font family, `'Arial Armenian'`, installed in your platform by calling `'Arial Armenian' in sg.Text.fonts_installed_list()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I checked, the font Arial Armenian is in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installed `Arial Armenian` font on my WIN10, and also the IME.

I don't know how to input Armenian, but it seems work fine, no "?"-s found.

```py
>>> 'Arial Armenian' in sg.Text.fonts_installed_list()
True
```

[image]

Of course, it show different characters on my console.

```py
You entered  Ö„Õ¸Õ¥Õ¼Õ¿Õ¨Ö‚Õ«Ö…Õº
```

Comment: how can this be possible?!
I've tried on another OS, and have the same problem with "?" -s, installed other fonts - got the same result, tried Windows default font for Armenian "Segoe UI", but no luck.
By saying installed the IME you mean Windows IME right?
So as I understand you just installed Arial Armenian font, copied and pasted my code and it worked right? This seems more OS issue than code am I right?

Comment: I downloaded the font `Arial Armenian.ttf` from http://www.hayfonts.com/, then installed it to my WIN10, also the Windows IME for Armenian. Run the same code in your question, it seems got right result on the GUI, but not correct characters on my command console by the statement `print`, of course, because the default font is not for Armenian on my WIN10, but not "?" -s displayed.

Comment: Problem solved!
Thanks to your reply, I understand that the code is correct and the problem is in OS, so I started digging WIN10 language settings and found out that my OS region settings "Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" checkbox is unchecked.
I checked it and everything worked! Now even without specifying font, the GUI works in Armenian.

Thank you once more for your support

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the code is correct and the problem is in OS, so I started digging WIN10 language settings and found out that my OS region settings "Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" checkbox is unchecked. I checked it and everything worked! Now even without specifying font, the GUI works in Armenian.

[image]